# Access 2007 SQL Merge tables without creating duplicates

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007

I would like to add the unique values of tblA to tblB without creating duplicate values based on multiple fields.  In the following example, FirstName and LastName determine a duplicate, Foo and Source are irrelevant.

tblA:

```
FirstName  LastName  Foo  Source
John       Doe       1    A
Jane       Doe       2    A
Steve      Smith     3    A
Bill       Johnson   2    A
```

tblB:

```
FirstName  LastName  Foo  Source
John       Doe       1    B
Bob        Smith     5    B
Steve      Smith     4    B
```

This is the result I want:

tblA:

```
FirstName  LastName  Foo  Source
John       Doe       1    A
Jane       Doe       2    A
Steve      Smith     3    A
Bill       Johnson   2    A
Bob        Smith     5    B
```

Here's an equivalent of the code I've tried:

`INSERT INTO tblA 

SELECT B.*
FROM tblB AS B 

LEFT JOIN tblA AS A ON A.FirstName = B.FirstName AND A.LastName = B.LastName 

WHERE A.FirstName IS NULL`

And this is the result I get:

tblA:

```
FirstName  LastName  Foo  Source
John       Doe       1    A
Jane       Doe       2    A
Steve      Smith     3    A
Bill       Johnson   2    A
John       Doe       1    B
Bob        Smith     5    B
```

Steve Smith from tblB is ignored, which is good.  John Doe from tblB is added, which is bad.  I've spent way too much time on this and I've inspected the data every way I can think of to ensure John Doe in tblA and tblB are the same first and last name.  Any ideas on what could be going wrong?

Update: FYI, on my real tblB, about 10,000 of 30,000 should be moved to tblA. This is actually moving over 21,000.  The problem is this is one step of a common process.

Comment: Regarding your recent edit, it is still valid to test one case as per my comment. If it proves to be hidden characters, then various other approaches can be considered, depending on the character. For example, Excel sometimes transfers with character 255, which looks like a space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I try:

```
SELECT tbb.*
FROM tbb 
LEFT JOIN tba 
ON (tbb.FirstName = tba.FirstName) 
   AND (tbb.LastName = tba.LastName)
WHERE (((tba.LastName) Is Null));
```

The only line returned is:

```
Bob        Smith     5    B
```

Is it possible that John Doe has a hidden character?

Comment: I do confirm the same. I have typed your tables I have done the SELECT and the INSERT

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I've tried looking for a hidden character and haven't found one. I have an Excel macro that identifies dupes based on the same fields and it IDs the offending rows as duplicates (after I export to Excel of course). How would you go about finding a hidden character if there was one?

Comment: You can try checking the field length `SELECT LastName, Len(LastName) FROM tblB`, you can also try emptying the fields and retyping for Doe to see if that produces the same problem. If that clears the problem, it is worth coding to clear hidden characters. Sometimes data does not transfer well between Excel and Access.

Comment: In my real data the criteria for a duplicate is 4 fields. While comparing text lengths I noticed the problematic entries have NULL in one or more of those fields. Is there a way for Access to recognize NULL = NULL in this situation?

Thank you again for the help.

Comment: It is always best to post examples that are close to reality. Null is not equal to null, however, you can append a zero length string to a field and test that: `WHERE tblA.Field1 & "" = tblB.Field1 & ""`

Comment: I just didn't realize the NULLs would be an issue here. During table creation, if one of the required fields would be NULL I add the text "#NULL" which will be easy to filter out later on.  Now I'm getting the expected results.  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

*Edit* : Sorry, it doesn't work on Access2007

You have many way to do that :

```
INSERT INTO tblA 
SELECT B.* FROM tblB AS B 
WHERE B.firstname, B.lastname NOT IN (select firstname, lastname from tblA)
```

Or

```
INSERT INTO tblA 
SELECT * FROM tblB
MINUS
SELECT * FROM tblA
```

Comment: are you sure both are access 2007 compatible?

Comment: Thank you for the reply.  Unfortunately, neither of these are compatible with Access 2007.  Equally unfortunate: I have to use Access 2007

Answer (score 0):

This one works in Access.

You can run it to infinity - it won't add more rows than needed:

```
INSERT INTO tblA
SELECT B.*
FROM tblB AS B
WHERE (((B.FirstName) Not In (select firstname from tblA))
AND ((B.LastName) Not In (select firstname from tblA)))
```

Comment: hi hansup 
thanks for your help with the text, it looks much better now